# How to group duplicated pairs and write queries on them?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I have the following table

```
Fruit  |   Price   |   Fruit   |   Price   |   State 
-----------------------------------------------------
apple  |     4     |   banana  |     3     |     NY
apple  |     6     |   banana  |     5     |     CA
apple  |     1     |   banana  |     2     |     PA
orange |     4     |   pear    |     5     |     FL
orange |     3     |   pear    |     4     |     OH
```

I want to ask the following question:

does **fruit1** cost more than **fruit2** in all states.

So ask that question for all pairs.

1. Does **apple** cost more than **banana** in all states?
2. Does **orange** cost more than **pear** in all states?
3. Continue to ask for any other existing pairs

So I'm assuming the query I need to write needs to somehow first group pairs that show up in multiple rows. How do I do that?

Comment: Why do you have two columns called `Fruit` and two columns called `Price`?  This won't even compile, I think.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: It's after a left join on the same table.

Comment: What is the ordering of the fruits in your table?  Can `(apple, banana)` and `(banana, apple)` _both_ occur?

Comment: No @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2):

So you would do:

```
select fruit1, fruit2
from t
group by fruit1, fruit2
having sum(price1 > price2) = count(*);
```

That is, do an aggregation.  Count the number of times that the price of fruit1 is greater than the price of fruit2.  If this is always true, then the count equals the total count.

If the data is all in one table:

```
select t1.fruit, t2.fruit
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.state = t2.state and t1.fruit <> t2.fruit
group by t1.fruit, t2.fruit
having sum(t1.price > t2.price) = count(*);
```

Comment: So if I wanted to check that they are all less than, or all greater than, would I just do having sum(price1 > price2) = count(*) OR sum(price1 < price2) = count(*)

Comment: Why do we do sum and not count?

Comment: @JamesMitchell Gordon is summing a boolean expression, which MySQL will resolve to 0 or 1.  So, if `price1 <= price2`, then this would return 0, and the sum/count comparison would fail (i.e. not a match).

Comment: @JamesMitchell . . . `COUNT()` counts the number of rows whose value is not `NULL`.  `SUM()` treats true as 1 and 0 as false, `SUM()` counts the number of times that the condition is true.